# Why am I having issues with my destructor when I use my ostream overloading operator?

Tags: c++

I am learning C++ and I was working on a project for my class. The project is a CityClock class that displays time, toggles format between the 24 and 12-hour clocks, and a tick function that adds one second to the time of the current object. I was then asked to add a move constructor, a move operator, a copy constructor, a copy operator, an overloading operator, and an overloaded ostream insertion operator. I was then to display that these parts worked in the main method.

Here are the project requirements:

> This is a continuation of project four. Extend Clock class and rename it to CityClock. A CityClock object has a name and shows time. These are example screen output: New York - 1:35:02 PM and New York - 13:35:02. CityClock class must use a pointer to a dynamic C-string to store city name. Keep toggleFormat, show and tick member functions. Make the following changes:
>
> 1. Add a destructor;
> 2. Change the default constructor so that it initializes city name to “Rochester, Michigan” and time to 0 o'clock.
> 3. Change the three argument constructor so that it takes a C-string as an additonal argument and intializes city name to the c-string, and initialize time as before.
> 4. Add a copy constructor;
> 5. Add a move constructor;
> 6. Add a copy assignment operator;
> 7. Add a move assignment operator;
> 8. Add a type conversion function that converts a CityClock object to a C++ string object.
> 9. Add an overloaded addition operator + so that a given number of seconds can be added to a CityClock object to obtain another CityClock object; and
> 10. Add an overloaded ostream insertion operator << so that a CityClock object can be inserted into an ostream object.
>
> In addition,
>
> - Write a main function that creates a few CityClock objects and invokes all public member functions and friend functions of CityClock class.
> - Update your makefile so that you can compile your program using make tool.
> - Compile your program and test run your program. Place sample output in a file named readme.

I got to the point where I was creating the overloaded ostream insertion operator and when I called it it seemed to work. but it called the destructor before displaying the operation that I was trying to do. Like I said I am new to this material, so I'm not quite sure why that is happening, what the problem is, or how to fix it. If anyone could help me understand whats going on here and how to fix it I would be grateful.

Here is my code:

CityClock.h :

```cpp
#ifndef CITYCLOCK_H
#define CITYCLOCK_H

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class CityClock {
private:
    int hours;
    int minutes;
    int seconds;
    bool is12HourFormat;
    char* cityName; // Pointer to store city name

public:
    CityClock(); // Default constructor
    CityClock(int h, int m, int s, const char* name); // Constructor with parameters
    CityClock(const CityClock& other); // copy constructor
    CityClock(CityClock&& other); // move constructor
    ~CityClock(); // Destructor
    CityClock& operator=(const CityClock& other); // copy operator
    CityClock& operator=(CityClock&& other); // move operator
    std::string toString() const; // Declaration of the toString() function
    CityClock operator+(int secondsToAdd) const; // Overloaded addition operator +
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const CityClock& clock);
    void toggleFormat(); // Toggles between 12-hour and 24-hour format
    void show(); // Displays time
    void tick(); // Advances time by one second
};

#endif
```

CityClock.cpp :

```cpp
#include "CityClock.h"
#include <cstring>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>


// Default Constructor
CityClock::CityClock() : hours(0), minutes(0), seconds(0), is12HourFormat(true), cityName(nullptr) {
    //set default city name
    cityName = new char[strlen("Rochester, Michcigan") + 1];
    strcpy(cityName,"Rochester, Michigan");
}

// Constructor with Parmeters
CityClock::CityClock(int h, int m, int s, const char* name) : is12HourFormat(true) {
    if (h >= 0 && h < 24 && m >= 0 && m < 60 && s >= 0 && s < 60) {
        hours = h;
        minutes = m;
        seconds = s;
    } else {
        std::cerr << "Invalid time input. Time set to 00:00:00.\n";
        hours = 0;
        minutes = 0;
        seconds = 0;
    }
    cityName = new char[strlen(name) +1];
    strcpy(cityName, name);
}

// Copy Constructor
CityClock::CityClock(const CityClock& other) : hours(other.hours), minutes(other.minutes), seconds(other.seconds), is12HourFormat(other.is12HourFormat){
        // Allocate memory for city name
        cityName = new char[strlen(other.cityName) + 1];
        // Copy city name
        strcpy(cityName, other.cityName);
    }

// Move Constuctor
CityClock::CityClock(CityClock&& other) {
    std::cout << "Move Constructor called." << std::endl;
    cityName = other.cityName;
    other.cityName = nullptr;
    seconds = other.seconds;
    minutes = other.minutes;
    is12HourFormat = other.is12HourFormat;
}

// Destructor
CityClock::~CityClock() {
    std::cout << "Destructor called for CityClock object." << std::endl;
    // Deallocate dynamically allocated memory
    delete[] cityName;
    
}

// Copy Operator
CityClock& CityClock::operator=(const CityClock& other) {
    if (this != &other) { // Check for self-assignment
        std::cout << "Copy Operator Called." << std::endl;
        // Copy the values from 'other' to 'this'
        hours = other.hours;
        minutes = other.minutes;
        seconds = other.seconds;
        is12HourFormat = other.is12HourFormat;
        
        // Deallocate the existing cityName memory
        delete[] cityName;
        
        // Allocate new memory for cityName and copy the name
        cityName = new char[strlen(other.cityName) + 1];
        strcpy(cityName, other.cityName);
    }
    return *this; // Return the current object after assignment
}

// Move Operator
CityClock& CityClock::operator=(CityClock&& other) {
    if (this != &other) { // Check for self-assignment
        std::cout << "Move Operator Called." << std::endl;
        // Transfer ownership of resources
        hours = other.hours;
        minutes = other.minutes;
        seconds = other.seconds;
        is12HourFormat = other.is12HourFormat;
        cityName = other.cityName;

        // Reset source object
        other.cityName = nullptr;
    }
    return *this;
}

std::string CityClock::toString() const {
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << cityName << " - Time: ";
    if (is12HourFormat) {
        int displayHours = hours % 12;
        if (displayHours == 0) displayHours = 12;
        ss << displayHours << ":";
    } else {
        ss << hours << ":";
    }
    if (minutes < 10) ss << "0"; // Add leading zero for minutes < 10
    ss << minutes << ":";
    if (seconds < 10) ss << "0"; // Add leading zero for seconds < 10
    ss << seconds;
    if (is12HourFormat) {
        if (hours < 12) {
            ss << " AM";
        } else {
            ss << " PM";
        }
    }
    return ss.str(); // Convert stringstream to string and return
}

CityClock CityClock::operator+(int secondsToAdd) const {
    // Create a new CityClock object with the updated time
    CityClock result(*this); // Copy constructor called to create a copy of the current object

    // Add the specified number of seconds to the time
    int totalSeconds = hours * 3600 + minutes * 60 + seconds + secondsToAdd;
    result.hours = totalSeconds / 3600 % 24;
    result.minutes = (totalSeconds % 3600) / 60;
    result.seconds = totalSeconds % 60;

    return result;
}

// Overloaded ostream insertion operator
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const CityClock& clock) {
    os << clock.toString(); // Use the toString() method to get the clock's string representation
    return os;
}

void CityClock::toggleFormat() {
    is12HourFormat = !is12HourFormat;
}

void CityClock::show() {
    std::cout << cityName << " - Time: ";
    if (is12HourFormat) {
        if (hours == 0) {
            std::cout << "12:";
        } else if (hours > 0 && hours <= 12) {
            std::cout << hours << ":";
        } else {
            std::cout << hours - 12 << ":";
        }
        // Add leading zeros for minutes and seconds if needed
        if (minutes < 10) {
            std::cout << "0";
        }
        std::cout << minutes << ":";
        if (seconds < 10) {
            std::cout << "0";
        }
        std::cout << seconds;
        if (hours < 12) {
            std::cout << " AM";
        } else {
            std::cout << " PM";
        }
    } 
    else {
        // Add leading zeros for minutes and seconds if needed
        if (minutes < 10) {
            std::cout << "0";
        }
        std::cout << hours << ":";
        if (seconds < 10) {
            std::cout << "0";
        }
        std::cout << minutes << ":";
        if (seconds < 10) {
            std::cout << "0";
        }
        std::cout << seconds;
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

void CityClock::tick() {
    seconds++;
    if (seconds >= 60) {
        seconds = 0;
        minutes++;
        if (minutes >= 60) {
            minutes = 0;
            hours++;
            if (hours >= 24) {
                hours = 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Main.cpp :

```cpp
#include "CityClock.h"

int main() {
    // Create CityClock objects
    
        CityClock clock1; // clock1 object using default constructor
        CityClock clock2(10, 30, 45, "New York"); // clock2 object using constructor with parameters

        std::cout << "Displaying clock1 object." << std::endl;
        clock1.show();

        std::cout << "Displaying clock1 object after toggling format to military time." << std::endl;
        clock1.toggleFormat();
        clock1.show();

        std::cout << "Displaying clock1 object after toggling format to standard time and using tick function" << std::endl;
        clock1.tick();
        clock1.toggleFormat();
        clock1.show();

        std::cout << "Displaying clock2 and then using the tick function and displaying that." << std::endl;
        clock2.show();
        clock2.tick();
        clock2.show();

        CityClock copiedClock(clock1); // copying clock 1 into the copiedClock object

        std::cout << "Displaying copiedClock which is a copy of Clock1 in its current instance." << std::endl;
        copiedClock.show();
        
        std::cout << "Displaying clock2 after using the copy operator to copy it to clock1" << std::endl;
        clock2 = clock1; // Using copy operator
        clock2.show();

        CityClock toBeMovedClock(0, 20, 20, "London"); // toBeMovedClock object that will be moved using move constructor
        std::cout << "Displaying toBeMovedClock that will be moved using move constructor." << std::endl;
        toBeMovedClock.show();
        
        CityClock movedClock(std::move(toBeMovedClock)); //movedClock object that will hold the old value of toBeMovedClock
        std::cout << "Displaying movedClock which was obtained from the previous toBeMovedClock." << std::endl;
        movedClock.show();
        
        std::cout << "Displaying toBeMovedClock2 that will be moved into movedClock." << std::endl;
        CityClock toBeMovedClock2(12 ,13, 33, "Paris"); // Creating toBeMovedClock2 to use Move operator on
        toBeMovedClock2.show();
        
        std::cout << "Displaying movedClock after the move operator moved toBeMovedClock2 into it." << std::endl;
        movedClock = std::move(toBeMovedClock2); // using move operator
        movedClock.show();

        std::cout << "Displaying clock2 that is using toString function." << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Clock info: " << clock2.toString() << std::endl; // Call the toString() function and print the result

        std::cout << "Displaying clock1 after using the overloading operator to add 7500 seconds." << std::endl;
        (clock1 + 7500).show(); // Using the overloading operator

        std::cout << "Displaying clock which is using the ostream insertion operator" << std::endl;
        CityClock clock(12, 30, 0, "New York");
        std::cout << "Clock: " << clock << std::endl; // Using the ostream overloading operator


    return 0;
}
```

Sample Output :

```
Displaying clock1 object.

Rochester, Michigan - Time: 12:00:00 AM

Displaying clock1 object after toggling format to military time.

Rochester, Michigan - Time: 00:00:00

Displaying clock1 object after toggling format to standard time and using tick function

Rochester, Michigan - Time: 12:00:01 AM

Displaying clock2 and then using the tick function and displaying that.

New York - Time: 10:30:45 AM

New York - Time: 10:30:46 AM

Displaying copiedClock which is a copy of Clock1 in its current instance.

Rochester, Michigan - Time: 12:00:01 AM

Displaying clock2 after using the copy operator to copy it to clock1

Copy Operator Called.

Rochester, Michigan - Time: 12:00:01 AM

Displaying toBeMovedClock that will be moved using move constructor.

London - Time: 12:20:20 AM

Move Constructor called.

Displaying movedClock which was obtained from the previous toBeMovedClock.

London - Time: 12:20:20 AM

Displaying toBeMovedClock2 that will be moved into movedClock.

Paris - Time: 12:13:33 PM

Displaying movedClock after the move operator moved toBeMovedClock2 into it.

Move Operator Called.
Paris - Time: 12:13:33 PM

Displaying clock2 that is using toString function.

Clock info: Rochester, Michigan - Time: 12:00:01 AM

Displaying clock1 after using the overloading operator to add 7500 seconds.

Rochester, Michigan - Time: 2:05:01 AM

Destructor called for CityClock object.

Displaying clock which is using the ostream insertion operator

Clock: New York - Time: 12:30:00 PM

Destructor called for CityClock object.

Destructor called for CityClock object.

Destructor called for CityClock object.

Destructor called for CityClock object.

Destructor called for CityClock object.

Destructor called for CityClock object.

Destructor called for CityClock object.
```

[image]

This is the part that confuses me:

```
Destructor called for CityClock object.

Displaying clock which is using the ostream insertion operator

Clock: New York - Time: 12:30:00 PM
```

I'm not quite sure why the destructor isn't called after I display the part above.

Comment: I don't see a problem with your output,  Can you add as text what the output should be and what output you get?

Comment: "must use a pointer to a dynamic C-string" Just bear in mind that you *never* do that in real life.

Comment: Also, please [edit] your question to show the sample output as text verbatim rather than linking to an image.

Comment: `(clock1 + 7500).show();` You add some seconds to an existing clock to create a new clock, which you then show. Where do you think the new clock goes after that?

Comment: Other than the leak in `CityClock& CityClock::operator=(CityClock&& other)` because it is missing `delete [] cityName;` before overwriting the pointer I'm not sure what that issue is you're having. It might help to print the address of the `this` pointer in the various constructors and destructor so you can match them up if there is confusion about destruction.

Comment: Please read about [mcve] and try to reduce your example to the minimum needed to illustrate the issue

Comment: I added the output as text and the specific part that I was wondering about.

Comment: Side note: I consider self assignment to be a logic error in the code that should be fixed rather than something to be ignored and `if (this != &other)` to be wasted CPU testing for something that should never happen. That said, I rarely go out looking for it and instead employ the [Copy and Swap idiom](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3279543/4581301) except where profiling has demonstrated that Copy and Swap results in a performance penalty that outweighs the simplicity of the implementation.

Comment: ` char* cityName; // Pointer to store city name` why are you still using "C" style strings. This is C++, so why don't you use `std::string cityName` that will prevent a lot of memory managment issues. (which you now have when you copy a City).

Comment: @user4581301 selfassignment is not always easy to prevent, suppose you have a `void foo(bar& a,bar& b)` and somewhere down, a couple of calls deeper there is `a = b`. When manual memory managment is involved ommiting the check can invoke UB. Here `strlen(other.cityName)` would try to get the lenght of a c-array that just has been deleted one line before.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai Don't I know it. I kill 'em when I can, but not all bugs are fixable. If I have to do a custom, non copy and swap assignment operator (in other words almost never), I'll start with a long and abort in the self-assignment test's else case. If the problem can't be resolved in a reasonable manner, I remove the abort.

Comment: @TroyUnger this question is closed, but the answer to your question is that the line `(clock1 + 7500).show();` creates a temporary `CityClock` object returned by the `+` operator.  after `show()` is called on the temporary, it is then destroyed. Splitting this into two lines:
`CityClock added = (clock1 + 7500); added.show();` causes the extra destruction line to go away.

Comment: *The project is a CityClock class that displays time, toggles format between the 24 and 12-hour clocks, and a tick function that adds one second to the time of the current object.* -- But instead, it turned into a project into trying to handle dynamically allocated memory.  If you had used `std::string`, your project would more than likely be working correctly, as you wouldn't need to code any user-defined copy constructor, assignment operator, or destructor.